# Chef templates and how to do a for loop in ruby

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am very new to ruby and chef.  I am trying to create entries in an nginx.conf file based on the number of cores.

```
for i in <%= node["cpu"]["total"]%>
upstream frontends {
        server 127.0.0.1:805x;
    }

end
```

So..if 4 cores the file will look like this:

```
upstream frontends {
            server 127.0.0.1:8051;
            server 127.0.0.1:8052;
            server 127.0.0.1:8053;
            server 127.0.0.1:8054;
        }
```

Comment: what if there are 16 cores? do you want port 8066 or port 80516 for the last one?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Recipe**

```
template "/etc/nginx/sites-available/my-site.conf" do
  variables :frontends_count => node["cpu"]["total"]
end
```

**Template**

```
upstream frontends {
<% @frontends_count.times do |i| %>
  server 127.0.0.1:805<%= i + 1 %>;
<% end %>
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with Chef, since I'm a Puppet user. Generally I would tackle it like this though:

```
n.times { |i| puts "server 127.0.0.1:805#{i+1}" }
```

Output:

```
server 127.0.0.1:8051
server 127.0.0.1:8052
server 127.0.0.1:8053
server 127.0.0.1:8054
```

Obviously you have to replace `n` by `node["cpu"]["total"]` (I assume that's an integer) and use something other than `puts`, but that should get you started. I guess this should work in Chef:

```
upstream frontends {
<% node["cpu"]["total"].times do |i| -%>
  <%= "server 127.0.0.1:805#{i+1}" %>
<% end -%>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with if statement.

Cookbook:

```
template "/opt/auth/users.xml" do
 ...
 variables(
   :users => auth_users
 )
end
```

Template:

```
<% @users.each do |u| %>
  <user username="<%= u['username'] %>" password="<%= u['password'] %>" roles="<%= u['roles'] if u['roles'] %>" groups="<%= u['groups'] if u['groups'] %>" />
<% end %>
```